# How to write matrix dimension without spaces in lyx?

Tags: lyx, matrices

Can I write "mxn" without the spaces in between? It looks weird because of the "-es" affix. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Mico! :)

Comment: `$m{\times}n$`?

Comment: I will add also two ticks `--`after `n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write

```
$m{\times}n$
```

Encasing the `\times` macro in curly braces changes its math status from `mathbin` to `mathord`. Spacing between math-ordinary items is tight. H